# Difference between fractional knapsack & greedy solution

Tags: algorithms, optimization, dynamic-programming, greedy-algorithms, knapsack-problems

I am trying to understand what the difference is between the fractional knapsack problem using dynamic programming, and the greedy solution version. Im looking at an example of the fractional problem which looks like:

[image]

What's the difference between that and the greedy solution? Are you not just taking the value-per-pound in this example too but it's just not explicitly stated?

Comment: The greedy solution to _what_? To fractional knapsack or regular knapsack?

Comment: What you mean by "the difference"? The two algorithms are very obviously not the same.

Answer (score 1):

The fractional Knapsack problem isn't solved using Dynamic Programming, but can be solved using a greedy algorithm. Item A is \$50/unit, B is \$5/unit and C is \$40/unit. The greedy method is to use as much of the highest value items as possible, which gives the solution on the image.

Dynamic Programming allows you to solve the problem when you cannot split the items.

Comment: "The fractional Knapsack problem isn't solved using Dynamic Programming" -- but it *can* solve it.